# C# GetMethod throw exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, generics

I had a generic method that I'd like to invoke, but it throws the exception below:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It's in fact the GetMethod(...) who equals to null.
But I can't find where I did wrong cause I had a very similar function in another class.
This is the code simple:

```
Class DatabaseSyncronizor
{
    ...
    internal void SyncronizeAll()
    {
           for(int i=0;i<MyList.Count();i++)
           {
                Type type=Type.GetType(MyModelClass);
                typeof(DatabaseSyncronizor).GetMethod("Synchronize",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance).MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(this, null);

            }
      }


    private void Syncronize<T>() where T :class,IDate
    {
         IGenericService<T> service = new GenericService<T>(new UnitOfWorkFactory(_connectionString));
         ...
    }
}
```

Thank you for you help!

Regards,
Léona

Comment: Obviously, GetMethod is unable to find the method. Please check the spelling of the method in question.

Comment: Please paste your code, don't type it into the box. `BingdingFlags` instead of `BindingFlags` is clearly a typo - and it's possible the cause of your issue is a typo - but we're unable to be certain unless we see the *exact* code.

Comment: What is the contents of the `MyModelClass` variable? And if your reaction to this is "that's not a variable, that's the name of the class" then this is illegal syntax: `Type.GetType(MyModelClass)`.

Comment: Thanks for all of you above. I made a spelling mistake....
Sorry for spamming the stackoverflow with this stupid question and using all your time to analyze my code :-(

Comment: This is not a complete waste...I arrived here after forgetting to add the NonPublic binding flag and your post solved my problem immediately. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method is called Syncronize not Synchronize.

Try this

```
typeof(DatabaseSyncronizor).GetMethod("Syncronize",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance)
                           .MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(this, null);
```

Comment: Is the anyway to make it throw "Method not found" exception? It took me some time to realise it's because I changed one of the parameters type. But the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is not very helpful.